# Sinatra-syncrony - NoMethodError at /

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying the get Sinatra-syncrony running. This seems to be a simple starting app, but I can't get it to work.

If I uncomment `require 'sinatra/synchrony'` the standard Sinatra app works fine.

Error:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
file: fiber_pool.rb | location: rescue in block in call | line: 24
```

App.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/synchrony'
require 'haml'

get '/' do
  haml :layout
end
```

views/layout.haml:

```
Hello World!
```

Running server with: `ruby -rubygems app.rb`

---

Setup:

- Ruby 1.9.2
- Sinatra 1.2.7 (Also tried 1.3.1)
- Sinatra-synchrony 0.3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you're using Webrick and it's cause of your error. Try to use an EventMachine-aware server such as Thin. For example, install thin gem and prepare following `config.ru` file:

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

After that run sinatra with that command: `rackup -s thin`

Comment: I was using Mongrel, but ye, might be the same. I'll try thin as soon as I can.